# XML GUI in Python

Tags: python, gtk, dock

I'm working on a project where someone wrote a PyGTK GUI that uses docks from GDL. He has the GUI saved as an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <object class="GtkUIManager" id="uimanager"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Title</property>
...
```

The code calls

```
self.dock_layout.load_from_file("gui_layout.xml")
```

I need to remove the GDL dependency. Can I still use the XML layout? If so, how?

Comment: Could you elaborate with some more information on what the XML layout looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [GtkBuilder](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkBuilder.html) file. You can use it, e.g.

```
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("gui_layout.xml")

window = builder.get_object("mainWindow")
```